# Make a div cover exactly the viewport

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<style >
  html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;  
    background:red;
  }
  #main {
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
  }
  h1 {
      margin:0;
  }
</style>

<body >
 <div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">
   Adjust the height
</div>
</body>
```

I want `div main` to cover the whole viewport without extending the screen further to the bottom. With the above code, a vertical scrollbar appears because we exceed the viewport height. How may I oblige `#main`to stop exactly at the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: You may need to add more details .. h1 has fixed height? browser support -flexbox is an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give a height to `<h1>` and based on it calculate the height of body.

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
  }
  #main {
    height: calc(100% - 35px);
    background: yellow;
  }
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
    height: 35px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">
  Adjust the height
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use flex to make this easy :

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}
#main {
  background: yellow;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
  }
  #main {
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    /* overflow:auto; depends on behavior expected when too much content */
  }
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Header within a div of any height </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    Adjust the height, should i scroll if too much content ? then add overflow:auto;
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set .main to position: absolute;, then use bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; to stretch it to all sides.

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;  
    background:red;
}
  #main {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:yellow;
  }
  h1 {
      margin:0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/841f9z5b/

Answer (score 0):

Using viewport units we can get the desired div cover
                html,body {
              height: 100vh;
              margin:0;
              background:red;
            }
            #main {
              height: 80vh;
              background:yellow;

```
        }
        h1 {
            margin:0;
          height:20vh;
        }
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBqQLq

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS calc` to set your div height dynamically.

***This will work with IE9 and above (so pretty much covers all modern browsers)***

```html
<style >
  html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;  
    background:red;
  }
  #main {
    height: calc(100% - 37px); /* Height of header subtracted*/
    background:yellow;
  }
  h1 {
      margin:0;
  }
</style>

<body >
 <div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">
   Adjust the height
</div>
</body>
```